# Does only search-and-matching predict bunching around minimum wage?

Tags: labor-economics, minimum-wage, search-and-matching

I heard a comment that search and matching models are empirically more valid than job-posting (even though the predictions are very similar) because with posting it is not possible to rationalize the bunching around the minimum wage cutoff. I don't understand why this should be?
[Here is the bunching article](https://academic.oup.com/qje/article/134/3/1405/5484905)